# queries to active live test health of a galera cluster

Tags: mariadb, galera, monitoring, alerts

What queries could be used to foresee or better fine tune alerts to check the health status of a Galera (MariaDB) cluster?

The problem I am facing is that randomly the cluster gest stalled because of a heavy DDL statement, so besides using tools like telegraf, that work great and help to get an overview of the cluster, currently I run periodically a query just writing data into a table, and if it times out I spawn an alert.

This works but is prone to create many false positives alerts, there is no configurable threshold based on X attempts, no execution time diffs between test so it can take 1 second or 10 to finish and there are no warnings, etc. so before trying to implement all the whistles and bells for alerting, and being aware that  many factors may influence, I would like to know what queries or type of them could be used periodically (every 30 seconds probably) in where the output could be a deterministic factor to trigger or not an alert.

For example a simple `ping`:

```
SELECT 1
```

Helps to very that serves is up and running but won't help much to check if a table is locked, etc.

Currently, I am using:

```
INSERT INTO table_rw (id, t) VALUES (?, ?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE t=?
```

Mainly to prevent filling up the table with useless data, but probably are better ways the ones that could help diagnose better without overloading to much the existing cluster.

How ideas?